# A mass of 100kg is lifted with a constant acceleration of 1m/s^2. Find the power delivered in lifting after 2s

Tags: physics

> Also find the power delivered by gravity

Displacement of the object 
$$s=\frac 12 at^2$$
$$s=\frac 12.4$$
$$s=2m$$
Work done
$$W=F.s$$
Force applied is 
$$F=ma$$
$$F=100$$
Therefore 
$$W=200J$$
Power
$$P=200/2=100W$$
But the answer is $2200W$. What’s going wrong?

Comment: Why don't you use the formula: Power = Force $\times$ velocity?

Comment: Yeah, I could use that. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that

$$F-mg =ma\implies F=1100 N \implies dW=F\cdot tdt \implies P(t)=\frac{dW}{dt}=F\cdot t$$

Note that

- the mean power is $\frac{W_{tot}}{t_{fin}}=1100 W$
- the power at time $t=2$ is $P(2)=F\cdot 2=2200 W$

Comment: Okay, that was a very bad mistake on my part. Thanks a lot though!

Comment: @Aditya You are welcome! Bye

Comment: The force acted by gravity is equal to $-1000 N$ therefore the power by gravity at time t=2 is equal to $-2000 W$. Indeed we had $200 W$ without gravity and we need $2000 W $ more to lift.